# Urinary Incontinence and Changing Adult Diapers

Tags: wudu, taharah, najis

Al Salam Alaykum. I am currently facing some urinary incontinene in the form drops leaking out every few seconds throughout the day. After reading many online fatwas, I have went and bought some adult diapers to keep my underwear clean. My issue is that they aren't cheap, and I read that I need to change the diaper every prayer. What should I do in this case? Should I combine my prayers and only change 3 times a day or should I wear one for the whole day?

Comment: Could you link to the fatwas? You can use a normal cloth, you do not require a diaper. And you can purify and reuse the cloth by washing.

Comment: Here is a link to one of the ones I found: http://aboutislam.net/counseling/ask-the-scholar/prayer/pray-diaper-always-filled-urine/ . Also thank you for your advice. Alhamdulellah, after going to the doctor and testing with white underwear, it turns out that I have a condition that feels like I'm about to urinate, but nothing comes out. Alhamdulellah.